# Node.js/Express - how to access session data through method(using sockets)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, session, express

I've stored some Oauth data in session, and now I'd like to access it again, so I created a local API endpoint to feed that access token. It appears that if I make that request via a method though, it doesn't contain the request body, so it can't actually get the `req.session.access_token`.

Visiting this endpoint provides the right data if typed into the address bar, but the response is undefined when requested through a method. The method is being called through a socket, if that helps inform the advice.

```
//This is the endpoint
app.get('/instagram/accesstoken', function(req,res){
  console.log("/instagram/accesstoken: ", req.session.access_token, ", req: ", req);
  res.json({access_token: req.session.access_token});
});

//This is the method calling the endpoint
function getAccessToken(callback){
  request({url: 'http://localhost:3000/instagram/accesstoken', method: "GET"}, function(err, resp, data){
  console.log("getAccessToken: ", data);
  if(err) { return callback(err); }
  callback(null, data);
});

//Sockets
io.listen(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  ...
  getAccessToken(function(err, token){...}
  ...
});
```

I'm open to alternative solutions as well. How can I feasibly get access to the session data? Thanks for your patience, and for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

Used express and socket.io for just a few days but here's a bit thought:
1. You're having problem getting `req.session`, which is picked up by the server from its session storage. The server does this with the help of *sessionid*(usually named sessionid or sid) stored in the browser *cookie*, which is sent in the headers of every request. So you should probably check the request headers(on the requests made after the socket connection) to see if the `cookie` is correctly sent and whether it is including the *sessionid* we want.
2. You're telling the client to request the `accesstoken` on your site when the socket connects so the server can get the Oauth access_token to request or send infomation to other apps(if I understand correctly). This is a bit of an overhead(one too many request) since you may just get the session id from [socket request's header](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#request:request) and then get this user's session data with it. However this may need a little tweak since the framework's session functionality can't check the session id from the `req` object automatically. This can be a bit difficult if the session functionality doesn't provide relevant functions so you'll have to dive in the framework. But it's an alternate if plan 1 doesn't work out(and is also more elegant since it saves one request :) (but may be harder as well :( ))

Answer (score 0):

To access session data via sockets you need to use a plugin like https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session

With this you can access session data via socket calls.